# Sharing data between AngularJS services

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

**Is there a way to share data between services in AngularJS?**

Use case: data aggregation from different services
For example I want a service1 that loads some data from a REST Service. Then another service2 adds additional data to the service1 data from another REST API to create a data aggregation service.

I basically want to separate the services based on the APIs that they use, but still have a service that holds all the data in the end.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a third service that uses the `$q` deferred library to combine the promises from the 2 API REST calls using `$q.all()`.

Then pass this third service to your controller as a dependency and use `$q.then()` to combine the results:

```js
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter');

app.factory('API_1',function($http){    
      return $http.get('dataSource-1.json');   
})

app.factory('API_2',function($http){    
      return $http.get('dataSource-2.json');   
});

app.factory('API_3',function($q,API_1,API_2){ 
 return $q.all([API_1,API_2]);
})
/* add "$q" and "API_3" as dependencies in controller*/
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$q,API_3) {

  $q.when(API_3).then(function(results) {
    /* combine the 2 API results arrays*/
    $scope.combinedData=[results[0].data,results[1].data];    

  });    


});
```

DEMO: **[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qvm5Yo5C15yQT5qMXq3a)**

Answer (score 11):

Since a service can depend on another service, this will work:

```
myApp.factory('myService1', function() {});
myApp.factory('myService2', function(myService1) {});
```

Note that they can't both depend on each other, or you'll get a `Circular dependency` error.