# Angular Service Factory Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

My understanding of angular services is that they are used to access external data sources amongst other things.

So let's assume I have a service to access feeds, that deals with the ATOM parsing, etc.

Now, let's assume a controller needs to access several feeds.

Is there a way for me to parameterize services as they are instantiated? Since services are singletons, do I need a service factory factory? Should I be using the same service and passing details of the particular feed each time? What if I need to make more than one calls to the same feed and would like a dedicated object to speak with? (think websockets instead of feeds).

Is there another approach altogether that would work for this?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313205/sharing-data-between-angularjs-services/15316971#15316971

Comment: Where does your app get the set of possible feeds?  Is this a known/fixed set, or is it dynamic -- i.e., can a user provide feed details at run time?

Comment: In my case it's fixed but it'd be interesting to know the answer for both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to parameterize services as they are instantiated?

Not really.  You can inject things into a service – e.g., another service – but I don't think that will help you here.

> Since services are singletons, do I need a service factory factory?

I don't know how you would write that, but again, I don't think it would help here.

> Should I be using the same service and passing details of the particular feed each time?

Well, as I asked in the comments, if you are dealing with a fixed set of feeds, I would hard-code them into the service (or maybe have the service fetch them from a configuration file on the server), and allow the controller to ask for them by name or some ID.

If you need something more dynamic, then I think you'd have to pass in the feed details to the service.

In either case, I think one "atomFeed" service would be sufficient.

> What if I need to make more than one call to the same feed and would like a dedicated object to speak with?

I would probably still use one service.  I'm not sure what the issue is here though.

Comment: I think you're right. Using one service to do all the talking with all the feeds is probably the way forward. Thanks.