# How to call a service from another service in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning Angular, and I defined a `LocalStorage` service as:

```
.service('LocalStorage', function() {
    var self = this;

    this.localStorageAvailable = function() {
        return typeof (Storage) !== "undefined";
    };

    this.set = function(key, value) {
        if (!self.localStorageAvailable()) return;
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    };

    this.get = function(key, defaultValue) {
        if (!self.localStorageAvailable()) return defaultValue;
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    };
})
```

Then I want to create another service which uses the `LocalStorage` service I just defined, but it gives:

> error: $LocalStorage is udefined.

```
.service('FilterSvc', ['LocalStorage', function ($LocalStorage) {
    var self = this;
    var key = "Settings";
    this.LoadSettings = function (universeCode) {
        if ($LocalStorage.get(key, "") === "") {
            ////load setting, otherwise reuse
            var result = "aaa";
            this.set(key, result);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Can someone help?

Comment: You've got a stray `$` in your variable name.

Comment: Possible duplication - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313205/sharing-data-between-angularjs-services

Answer (score 1):

You should remove **$** from variable $LocalStorage

Comment: realised that and changed now, but when I call the function FilterSvc.LoadSettings('jerry'), the LocalStorage becomes undefined again. do I need to put LocalStorage into scope or something?

Comment: doesn't matter what you pass as name in function argument when dependency array exists. That's the whole point of the dependency array

Answer (score 0):

Use `self`

```
var self =  this;
```

and then call the function like below

```
 .........
self.servicefunction();
............
```

replace `this` with `self` for all your functions; its the key reason for confusion even with seasoned programmers.

PS: you have declared `var self = this` and not used it